# Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code but I have error

> Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "physical_therapy");
$conn->query("SET NAMES UTF8");

$id = $_POST["id"];
$fn = $_POST["Cus_Name"];
$age = $_POST["Cus_Age"];
$address = $_POST["Cus_Address"];
$phone = $_POST['Cus_Phone'];
$em = $_POST['Cus_Email'];
$pwd = $_POST["Cus_Password"];
$gender = $_POST["Cus_Gender"];



if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE customer SET 
Cus_Name='" . $fn . "', 
Cus_Age='" . $age . "', 
Cus_Address='" . $address . "', 
Cus_Phone='" . $phone . "',
Cus_Password='" . $pwd . "', 
Cus_Email='" . $em . "',
Cus_Gender='" . $gender . "' 
WHERE Cus_id=" . $id;

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Update Successfully!!<br><br>";
    echo "<a href=\"ProfileCus.php\">Go to Home</a>";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

Comment: Is there a space between  gender and WHERE?
Recommend dump the string to output and tinker with it in mysql workbench or phpmyadmin until it works, the error will soon reveal itself.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($sql);`? maybe there is a `'` in the data or the `$id` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons why the query doesn't work:

- There is a `'` in your data which is breaking your SQL.
- The `$id` is empty.

You should also use prepared statements to avoid sql injections:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "physical_therapy");
$conn->query("SET NAMES UTF8");

$id = $_POST["id"];
$fn = $_POST["Cus_Name"];
$age = $_POST["Cus_Age"];
$address = $_POST["Cus_Address"];
$phone = $_POST['Cus_Phone'];
$em = $_POST['Cus_Email'];
$pwd = $_POST["Cus_Password"];
$gender = $_POST["Cus_Gender"];

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = 'UPDATE customer SET Cus_Name = ?, Cus_Age = ?, Cus_Address = ?, Cus_Phone = ?, Cus_Password = ?, Cus_Email = ?, Cus_Gender = ? WHERE Cus_id = ?';

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $fn);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $age);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $address);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $phone);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $pwd);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $em);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $gender);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Update Successfully!!<br><br>";
        echo "<a href=\"ProfileCus.php\">Go to Home</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```